# C++ template type breaks where typedef works

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typedef

I'm currently stumped by a IMHO strange problem: Using a template breaks compilation, where using a typedef works just fine. The function I'm writing is intended to determine the Analytic Signal from a real valued time series with the following signature

```
#ifndef USE_TEMPLATE
typedef sample_t sample_T
#else
template<typename sample_T>
#endif
analytic_err analytic(
    size_t length,
    sample_T const * const signal,
    sample_T * const amplitude,
    sample_T * const phase )
{
    typedef kissfft<sample_T> kissfft_t;
    /* ... */
```

`kissfft` is the C++ variant of the KissFFT fast fourier transform library. A few lines further I allocate some work area arrays.

```
    kissfft_t::cpx_type *inout = new kissfft_t::cpx_type[padded_length];
```

I'm deliberately **not** using a std::vector and I did also modify kissfft.hh to be STL-less. I don't want to discuss the use or disuse of STL. In this project the STL is a no-go *(not my decision)*.

And that's where the trouble starts. If I *don't* use the template variant, i.e. define a typedef from `sample_t` to `sample_T` everything works just fine and the resulting program passes all the test cases.

*Trouble starts as soon as I switch to the use of templates:*

Both GCC and Clang bail out with some error I am unable to make sense of:

#### GCC error

```
In file included from /home/dw/extradev/octuda/src/hilbert_test.cc:6:0:
signalprocess.cc: In function ‘analytic_err analytic(size_t, const sample_T*, samplT*, sample_T*)’:
signalprocess.cc:54:23: error: ‘inout’ was not declared in this scope
signalprocess.cc:54:35: error: expected type-specifier
signalprocess.cc:54:35: error: expected ‘;’
signalprocess.cc: In instantiation of ‘analytic_err analytic(size_t, const sample_T sample_T*, sample_T*) [with sample_T = float; analytic_err = analytic_err_t; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
test_analytic.cc:45:41:   required from here
signalprocess.cc:54:2: error: dependent-name ‘kissfft_t:: cpx_type’ is parsed as a n-type, but instantiation yields a type
signalprocess.cc:54:2: note: say ‘typename kissfft_t:: cpx_type’ if a type is meant
signalprocess.cc:59:2: error: dependent-name ‘kissfft_t:: cpx_type’ is parsed as a n-type, but instantiation yields a type
signalprocess.cc:59:2: note: say ‘typename kissfft_t:: cpx_type’ if a type is meant
```

#### Clang error

```
In file included from ../../src/hilbert_test.cc:6:
signalprocess.cc:54:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'inout'
        kissfft_t::cpx_type *inout = new kissfft_t::cpx_type[padded_length];
                             ^
signalprocess.cc:54:35: error: expected a type
        kissfft_t::cpx_type *inout = new kissfft_t::cpx_type[padded_length];
                                         ^
signalprocess.cc:55:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'inout'
        if(!inout) {
            ^

and some more all following the same gist.
```

GCC and Clang to agree that something is not right when using templates. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using template, then this

```
kissfft_t::cpx_type *inout = new kissfft_t::cpx_type[padded_length];
```

should become this:

```
typename kissfft_t::cpx_type *inout = new typename kissfft_t::cpx_type[padded_length];
^^^^^^^^note                              ^^^^^^^^note
```

Because `kissfft_t` depends on the template argument, and as such `cpx_type` is a *dependent* type, hence you need to use `typename` to disambiguate it from static value.

To know in detail as to why `typename` is required, see this topic:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Could you please also explain, *why* I have to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

If `sample_T` is a template parameter, then `kissfft_t::cpx_type` is a dependent name. The compiler cannot deduce that it is a typename until the template is instantiated, so it needs to be written as `typename kissfft_t::cpx_type`.

If it isn't a template parameter, then putting `typename` there is an error, so unfortunately you'll need to add more hideous preprocessor shenanigans in order to do the right thing whether or not `USE_TEMPLATE` is defined.